# How to update UI when using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

My simple app is set to retrieve RSS feeds when the `Refresh` button is clicked.
Clicking the refresh button starts an `AsyncTask` which retrieves the feeds.  The `AsyncTask` is a subcalss of the main activity.

Here is what my class looks like:

```
public class NasaDailyImage extends Activity{
    public ProgressDialog modalDialog = null; //problematic
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        //instantiate the ProgressDialog
        Button b = //get reference to button
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                modalDialog.show(); // show modal
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting feeds", 500).show();
                new AsyncRetriever().execute(new IotdHandler()); // Get the feeds !!
            }
        });
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public synchronized void resetDisplay(boolean parseErrorOccured, 
        boolean imageErrorOccured,
        IotdHandler newFeeds){
        if(parseErrorOccured || imageErrorOccured){
            // make a Toast
            // do not update display
        }else{
            // make a Toast
            // update display
            // based on new feed
        }
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class AsyncRetriever extends AsyncTask<IotdHandler,Void,IotdHandler>{

        @Override
        protected IotdHandler doInBackground(IotdHandler... arg0) {
            IotdHandler handler = arg0[0];
            handler.processFeed(); // get the RSS feed data !
            return handler;
        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(IotdHandler fromInBackground){
            resetDisplay( // call to update the display
            fromInBackground.errorOccured,
            fromInBackground.imageError,
            fromInBackground);
        }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------


}
```

The problem is with `show()` of `modalDialog` in the `onCLickListener`. That causes my app to crash. **Why?** and **how do I solve it?**

Comment: *Without the `show()`, the app runs fine*

Comment: I don't see where you're creating any sort of dialog. It's null, so you can't `show()` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ProgressDialog` is `null` so you get `NPE` when you call `show()` on it. Instantiate it before calling a method on it.

Probably somewhere like here instantiate it then set the message, title, whatever you want before showing it

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    //instantiate the ProgressDialog

   // can set message, title, etc. here

    Button b = //get reference to button
   b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { 
    modalDialog = ProgressDialog.show(NasaDailyImage .this, "Enter Title", "Enter Message");
```

Comment: Ok a few other questions: Why doesnt app crash when I make a `Toast` in `onClickListener` ?? That isn't on the UI thread right ? AFAIK only UI  thread can make changes to UI

Comment: That is on the `UI Thread`. You also need to call `show()` in a static way

Comment: onClick method is working inside UI thread. Your toast works, because you instantiated it using this: Toast.makeText(...). While your modalDialog is null

Comment: Everything I see in your code so far is on the `UI Thread` except for `doInBackground()`

Answer (score 2):

Cannot update ui on the background thread. doinBAckground is invoked on the background thread. You should use progress dialog to show like Async Task and then you can change anything in your user interface (UI).

Step 1 : First initialize your your progress dialog.

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

Step 2: Then start your doBackground work below the progress dialog start.

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Activity1.this, "",
                        "Loading...");
```

Step 3: Finally dismiss your progress dialog after your works done.

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

In the mean time of progress dialog you can change any ui

Comment: Wait, I have a few more confusions regarding updating UI. I will post that as a separate question.

Comment: Sure. Please proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate ProgressDialog:

```
modalDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Please, wait...");
```